# Using tkinter grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I am fairly new to using .grid in tkinter and was wondering how I could get the `l2` variable to be right under the `l1` variable. When the code is run the 2nd label is too far down (even have to resize window). I would like to be able to place it in a specific place (below `l1`) but I'm not sure how to.

Thank you.

Example:

## Welcome

Please log-in to continue

Gap's a little big there as well.

Current code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1300x720")
myImage = PhotoImage(file='ssf.png')
label = Label(image=myImage)
label.grid(row=0)
label.image = myImage
l1 = Label(root, text="Welcome", font="Arial 100 bold",  anchor="e").grid(row=0, column=1)
l2 = Label(root, text="Please log-in to continue.", font="Arial 30 bold", anchor="e").grid(row=10, column=1)
```

[Preview of how it looks](https://gyazo.com/82bca3ed274efbb1217fa12ee7bf018a)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use the Frame widget to put the text in it like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1300x720")

myImage = PhotoImage(file='ssf.png')
label = Label(image=myImage)
label.grid(row=0)
label.image = myImage

labelFrame = Frame(root)
labelFrame.grid(row=0,column=1)

l1 = Label(labelFrame, text="Welcome", font="Arial 100 bold",  anchor="e")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
l2 = Label(labelFrame, text="Please log-in to continue.", font="Arial 30 bold", anchor="e")
l2.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

The Frame widget is in row 0, column 1 and contains 'l1' and 'l2'.

Comment: Thank you! But how would I go around aligning it to the left?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly do you want to align to the left?

Comment: Whoops, I mean the label "Please log-in to continue" slightly to the left so it's right next to the blue rectangle and any other widget I decide to add later.

Comment: add 'sticky="w"' when adding 'l2' to grid like this `l2.grid(row=1, column=0,sticky='w')`. `sticky="w"` will make the text go to the left(ie: west).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

1. Pls see my comments in the revised code below.
2. I would recommend drawing out the grid system on paper to visualise
   your layout and compare it with what is created by your program.
   Activating the background color of the widgets such as frame and
   label will help you  visualize your creation.
3. Recommend reading these references.
   http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html
   http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/layout-mgt.html

Happy coding. :)

```
#from tkinter import *
#from tkinter.ttk import *
## I suggest you abbreviate the imported modules to help you keep track of which
## module methods/functions you are using. See below. To be consistent, we will
## use ttk widgets where possible.

# Load tkinter for python 3
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1300x720")

# Customise style of ttk widgets
# I have added this to help you visualise the grid system.
s=ttk.Style()
s.configure('frame1.TFrame', background='pink')
s.configure('l0.TLabel', background='blue')
s.configure('l1.TLabel', background='green')
s.configure('l2.TLabel', background='brown')

# Create a frame inside root to contain all the widgets.
# The frame contains a 2x2 grid.
frame1 = ttk.Frame(root, style='frame1.TFrame', borderwidth=20, relief=tk.SUNKEN )
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')

# Load Image
# Added tk in fromt of PhotoImage.
myImage = tk.PhotoImage(file='ssf.png')

# Create a ttk.label to contain image
## I added ttk in front of Label. If not, it will mean you will use tk.Label instead of ttk.Label.
## Also I added frame1 as the 1st option to the ttk.Label to mean the ttk.Label
## is inside frame1.
## The "in_=frame1" option is added to grid to mean l0 is grid inside frame1 grid system.
l0 = ttk.Label(frame1, image=myImage, width=500)  
l0.grid(in_=frame1, row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
#label.image = myImage

# Create a ttk.Label to contain l1
l1 = ttk.Label(frame1, text="Welcome", style='l1.TLabel', font="Arial 100 bold", anchor=tk.E)
l1.grid(in_=frame1, row=0, column=1)
#l1 = Label(root, text="Welcome", font="Arial 100 bold",  anchor="e").grid(row=0, column=1)

# Create a ttk.Label to contain l2
l2 = ttk.Label(frame1, text="Please log-in to continue.", style='l2.TLabel', font="Arial 30 bold")
l2.grid(in_=frame1, row=1, column=1)
#l2 = Label(root, text="Please log-in to continue.", font="Arial 30 bold", anchor="e").grid(row=10, column=1)

# These configuration settings will let the grid columns and rows scale according
# to the changing size of the Window i.e. root.
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame1.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```